# Exclude ef virtual properties from swagger response

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I added Swashbuckle to a .net core web-api project using ef-core.
My problem is that the virtual properties of my ef autogenerated classes are added to the swagger example responses, this is making the responses huge, i just want to display the table properties, not the relations.

Example of code from the controller:

```cs
[HttpGet("devices", Name = "GetDevices")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Device>>> Devices()
{
    var devices = await _deviceDa.GetDevices();
    return Json(devices);
}
```

My problem is that the ef autogenerated classes are in a separated class library that i don't have access to change. I can't simply add JsonIgnore to these virtual properties.

Is it possible to get Swashbuckle to ignore all virtual properties?

Comment: What if you use ViewModels? Looks like you are returning the object itself, this is not a good practice, you should always return a DTO (Data Transfer Object) instead. Then on the DTO you can set wich properties you want to return.

Comment: This runs on a microservice architecture, this particular service is just a rest interface for the SQL-database, then there is an additional microservice that can provide various DTO-endpoints for the user-table for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your own `ContractResolver` to ignore the virtual property while serializing the model.

1. `IgnoreVirtualContractResolver`

   ```
   public class IgnoreVirtualContractResolver: DefaultContractResolver
   {
       protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
       {
           JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
           var propInfo = member as PropertyInfo;
           if (propInfo != null)
           {
               if (propInfo.GetMethod.IsVirtual && !propInfo.GetMethod.IsFinal)
               {
                   prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => false;
               }
           }
           return prop;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register

   ```
   services.AddMvc()
           .AddJsonOptions(options => {
               options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new IgnoreVirtualContractResolver();
           }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the view model instead of the original model and put the fields to display in the view model.
Instead of the original model, send the view model to the client

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities come to mind:
First use automapper to map to a POCO of yours. Problem is that you need to pocos, but on the other hand you gain a lot of control you need anyway later.

Or you could use ODATA directly, which essentially solves your problem AND gives you querying capabilites for free.